# Error 'xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code' after trying publishing Pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Command 'pod trunk push --verbose' outputs the following:

```
Build settings from command line:
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = -
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.1

=== CLEAN TARGET GTNetworkQualityChecker OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3   -[XCCompilerSpecificationIBStoryboardLinker _outputNodesForInputNodes:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4   -[XCCompilerSpecificationIBStoryboardLinker doSpecialDependencySetupForCommand:withInputNodes:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5   -[XCCommandLineToolSpecification createCommandsforInputs:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   -[PBXTargetBuildContext invokeTask:forInputs:withMacroExpansionScope:optionTable:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7   -[XCDependencyGraphCreationContext invokeTask:forInputs:withMacroExpansionScope:optionTable:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8   -[XCCompilerSpecification computeDependenciesForInputNodes:ofType:variant:architecture:outputDirectory:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9   -[XCCompilerSpecification computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:outputDirectory:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   -[XCBuildRuleDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:withOutputDirectory:parameterMacros:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[XCBuildRuleDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:withOutputDirectory:parameterMacros:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:processedPaths:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14   -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15   -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16   -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17   -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18   -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19   -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20   -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21   -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22   -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 23   -[XCBlockQueue _processNextBlockInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 24   -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 25   __NSThread__start__ (in Foundation)
 26   _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 27   _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 28   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

 -> GTNetworkQualityChecker (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
```

I've Xcode 8.1, Cocoapods v 1.2.0. Pod's repository is [here](https://github.com/Ar7Style/GTNetworkQualityChecker).

Could anybody tell me reason of that problem and how It may be fixed?

Comment: when I try to validate your repo via `pod spec lint --verbose GTNetworkQualityChecker.podspec`, I'm getting an error about a missing `FrameworkStoryboard.storyboard`.  I don't see that checked into your repo.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann yeah, do you know why project wants to find this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes down to this line in your podspec:

```
s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/Ar7Style/GTNetworkQualityChecker.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

The `:tag` is the problem.  Your current pod validation doesn't know which commit represents the definitive end of what you want to release, which would be your "`0.1.0`" version.  That's why the validation step is referring to an older version of your repo (where you did have `FrameworkStoryboard.storyboard` existing [before you deleted it](https://github.com/Ar7Style/GTNetworkQualityChecker/commit/9efdcb7c1b5f750fb1d75b001eb52b48387d3cc3)).

In other words, [you need to tag your Pod with a tag that corresponds to your version number](http://theonlylars.com/blog/2013/01/20/cocoapods-creating-a-pod-spec/).

For example, at the command line:

```
git tag '0.1.0' # the version number you're using for this release
git push --tags
```

Then do the validation step that I showed you up above:

```
pod spec lint --verbose GTNetworkQualityChecker.podspec
```

And if it passes, then you should do your `pod trunk push --verbose`.

Answer (score 2):

This error may occur when u setting up incorrect path to your sources. Check it one more time.
It should be something like:

```
s.source_files = "EXPLogger/*.{h,m,swift}"
```

Answer (score 1):

StoryBoard cant be a source file in Cocoapods.
If you want to add it to Cocoapods please add it to a resources filepattern

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after `pod spec lint` command, because I was using unavailable version of Swift in my podspec file(s.swift_version), it was version 6 which does not exist.