# CocoaPod - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, lint

I created a simple basic cocoaPod trying to get the hang of making one.

I followed the tutorial on raywnderlich

this is my pod spec file

```
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|

      s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
      s.ios.deployment_target = "9.0"
      s.name         = "StringyImage"
      s.summary      = "This Lib create an Image out of text fitting the rectangle that is passed"
      s.requires_arc = false

      s.version      = "1.0.3"

      s.license      = { :type => "#########", :file => "LICENSE" }

      s.author       = { "#### ###" => "###@###.com" }

      s.homepage     = "http://myGitRepoAtHome/iOS/StringyImage"

      s.source       = { :git => "http://LOGIN_INFO@myGitRepoAtHome/iOS/StringyImage.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

      s.framework  = "Fondation"

      s.source_files  = "StringyImage", "StringyImage/**/*.{swift}"

    s.description  = <<-DESC
    This Lib create an Image out of text fitting the rectangle that is passed. This will use a font that is veter base so we can resize it at will and keep the image clean
                       DESC
end
```

and when I run lint on it I get this error.

```
-> StringyImage (1.0.3)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_rename - (/private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/pascale.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/StringyImage.xcscheme, /private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/StringyImage.xcscheme))
```

So I wonder what is wrong with my podSpec ??

EDIT 1 : I was missing the "end" tag in the podspec here. but this was actually already in the actual podspec file.

Edit 2:

```
  StringyImage (1.0.3) - Analyzing on iOS 9.0 platform.
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-App`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `StringyImage` from `/Users/###/Documents/Libraries/StringyImage/StringyImage.podspec`

Resolving dependencies of 

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A StringyImage

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing StringyImage (1.0.3)
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/bin/git clone http://####@myGitRepoAtHome/iOS/StringyImage.git /var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/d20170404-18617-l6esrk --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch
     1.0.3
     Cloning into '/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/d20170404-18617-l6esrk'...
     Note: checking out 'f75b7e574be6e39ce590b85b1c3181d82c7d1a48'.

     You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
     changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
     state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

     If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
     do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

       git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

  > Copying StringyImage from `/Users/###/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/StringyImage/32a989f5e9af15edc8e48b268e67bcf3-1053f` to
  `../../../../../private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/StringyImage`
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `Pods-App` iOS 9.0
      - Generating Info.plist file at `../../../../../private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at `../../../../../private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at `../../../../../private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-umbrella.h`
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `../../../../../private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
  - Writing Lockfile in `../../../../../var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `../../../../../private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `App.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

Integrating target `Pods-App` (`../../../../../var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/App.xcodeproj` project)
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' to project.
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' to project.
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock' to project.
  - Running post install hooks

-> Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
 -> StringyImage (1.0.3)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_rename - (/private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/pascale.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/StringyImage.xcscheme, /private/var/folders/bv/0pq17ll10bjff4kfp3p8p6000000gr/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/StringyImage.xcscheme)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:462:in `rename'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:462:in `block in mv'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:1454:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:1470:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:1452:in `fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:451:in `mv'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.2/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb:244:in `share_scheme'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:431:in `add_app_project_import'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:307:in `block in perform_extensive_analysis'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:298:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:298:in `perform_extensive_analysis'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:79:in `validate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:67:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:55:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
) during validation.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:84:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1.beta.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

There is that part talking about detached head.. But I did check my git repo and it good. it has its head on strait ;)

Comment: Take a look at this issue.  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6538.  Can you use the `--verbose` flag when you lint?

Comment: Yes I can use the flag. I just did not want for the moment to post the full lint report. ... its kind of long. but if it helps. I can put it an edit.

Comment: pod installation is 1.2.1.beta.1 .. so I guess form the like you gave I may want to down grade?

Comment: did you tag your git repo before trying to validate?  I [answered a question about this very thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193296/error-xcodebuild-returned-an-unsuccessful-exit-code-after-trying-publishing-p/43208619#43208619) earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `end` at the bottom of the file that closes out the `do |s|` loop

**EDIT**
You have a typo - `Fondation` != `Foundation`

```
s.framework  = "Foundation"
```

You shouldn't need to require Foundation anyway

Comment: The tag is already in my actual podspec, looks like I did not copy it here when I created the question. thanks for pointing it out.  :)

Comment: Still getting the same error. I also tried to just remove that line and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

`s.version` in spec file should match tag.
In my case tag was `0.0.1`. So `s.version` should be 0.0.1.